# What does "unimpressed" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

I don't completely understand its meaning in the sentence below.

> Because of its lack of theaters, the city came, ironically, to be viewed as an **unimpressed** theater town, and that reputation led entrepreneurs to believe that it would be shrewd to build new theaters there.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this is just a wrong answer to a GRE test: http://www.urch.com/forums/gre-sentence-completions/47608-real-19-test-2-1-a.html

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock:  I think you are right.  The answer I got must be a typo which confused me.  Thanks!

Comment: But think maybe we should leave this question because people who get the same copy of answers might also be confused and find the correct explanation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the context, I'd judge it to mean *undeveloped* or *untapped* (as in an *untapped market*).

No dictionary that I've found so far lists this sort of meaning, though.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I would take this to mean "not easily impressed, jaded."  But it doesn't matter, because it's meant to be wrong.